# htaccess rules not being accessed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have installed Apache on Ubuntu using the command **sudo apt-get install apache2**.

I have set the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file line: **AllowOverride nome** to **AllowOverride All**.

After that I created the file .htacess in /var/www/html folder... my index.html file is in there too.

I tested a simple .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /foobar/ https://example.com
```

It does not work, however. When I try the link http://naturalbela.com.br/foobar/, it is not redirected to https://example.com.

What may I be doing wrong?

Comment: But _where_ have you set `AllowOverride All`? It needs to be set for this specific directory (the document root), not higher up the directory tree in the main server config. `RewriteEngine` and `Redirect` directives are unrelated and belong to different modules (mod_rewrite and mod_alias respectively). You should remove the `RewriteEngine` directive if you are just using `Redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure that your .htaccess and index.html files are present in same folder(root or wherever you are keeping them).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
##Redirect to example.com when foobar is hit.
RewriteRule ^foobar/ https://example.com [R=301,NC,L]
##Rewrite example.com to index.html in backend.
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Still not working. I believe it is not being called, eve though .htaccess and the index.html are in the same folder.

Comment: @Siqueira, try checking if your htaccess file is enabled or not. Put a dummy line like `-------------` in your htaccess file save it and then hit any url if you get 500 internal error means your htaccess is enabled else you need to enable it, let me know how it goes.

Comment: I do not get this500 internal error. I think it is not enabled, but I have set AllowOverride All already. What else should I do no enable it?

Comment: @Siqueira, yeah its not enabled see link https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-set-up-enable-htaccess-apache once and then try my rules, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok... I missed setting AllowOverride on <Directory /var/www/> ... I did it and set the .htaccess file to the rules you wrote and now I get "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." ... you can check it here http://www.naturalbela.com.br/

Comment: @Siqueira, could you please do let me know if you have any other rules apart from these in your htaccess file?

Comment: @Siqueira You may not have mod_rewrite installed. However, you don't need necessarily need mod_rewrite for this. The single `Redirect` directive you had in the question (less the `RewriteEngine` directive) is sufficient - if that is all you want to do (redirect from A to B).